# Count the numbers of members meeting two criteria?

Tags: excel, cell, countif

**How do you count the numbers of members in my table?**

The table is called `Table2`. I would like to see the amount of people that meet the criteria of having the membership code of A3 (changing when it moves down a cell) and pay by either `Annual Membership 1`, or `Annual membership 2`.

Comment: Better if you can provide the sample dataset and expected output.

Comment: This is not a Free coder site. Try it yourself, then ask for help if you have problems.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried it myself, I have tried countif, this works for the membership code, but when i try a countifs, then i get a result of 0. I have also tried 'sumif', 'if', 'and' etc but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend three ways of going about this, in descending order of preference.

1. Use a pivot table to summarise the data into a cross table, if
   there is a new type of payment code it automatically be reflected,
   you don't need to do complex formulae, only make sure the input
   range used for the pivot table includes all the data. You need to
   manually refresh the Pivot table.
2. Use the sumifs() function (you can sum a cell with 1 as value),
   research a bit on multiple conditions, there is plenty of info out
   there (apparently `sumifs()` supports up to 29), I can suggest
   [this one](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-sumifs-to-sum-by-multiple-conditions-in-excel/)
3. Sometimes I just use the formula `=B1&"-"&C1&"-"D1` (into a fourth E
   column) to combine the two or more cells I want to test into a
   single text value and then do the `countif()` or `sumif()`. It is quick
   and dirty but can be very easy to understand and has the benefit
   that at each row you have some value you could filter for using the
   data filter functionality. You can also use an `OR()` and `IF()` to
   create the condition at each row that would yield "True" or other
   value that is  more meaningful (e.g.
   I`f(And(A1="A3",Or(B1="Membership 1",B1="Membership
   2")),"VIP","Regular")`, then use the `countif()` at the bottom to count
   the VIPs.
4. You can use also array formulas but I found them
   difficult to maintain and I don't have enough real life experience
   of using it.

Note: I didn't test the formulae, this is illustrative to give you a start, my advise is you use pivots if you only need a summary reporting.

Good luck!